# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap_info.txt'

Tags: android, itext

its my code :

```
 public  void CreateDirectory() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "pdfdemo");
        if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
            pdfFolder.mkdir();
        }


        //Create time stamp
        Date date = new Date() ;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date);

        File myFile = new File(pdfFolder + timeStamp + ".pdf");

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

        //Initialize PDF writer
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(myFile.getPath());

        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);

        //Add paragraph to the document

    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));

    document.close();
}
```

and in build.gradle :

```
    dependencies {

    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.0.2'

}
```

but when i am trying to run the program it gives me that error :

More than one file was found with OS independent path 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap_info.txt'

what sholud i do ?

Comment: *"it gives me that error"* - please share the stack trace, too.

Answer (score 7):

The code below in build.gradle fixed it for me

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap_info.txt'
        exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/*'
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. What's the downside of doing this though?

Answer (score 0):

In my case disabling `Firebase` plugin work fine

Comment: I am having same issue, but no firebase plugin.